# Adding buttons to MahApps.Metro Group box header

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

I'd like to be able to add icon buttons to the Mahapps.Metro Groupbox header. Is this possible? If anyone has done this, some sample code or pointing me to the necessary documentation would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to add any element that you want to the `Header` property of the `GroupBox`:

```
<GroupBox>
    <GroupBox.Header>
        <StackPanel>
            <Image Source="pic.png" Stretch="None"/>
            <TextBlock Text="header..." />
        </StackPanel>
    </GroupBox.Header>
</GroupBox>
```

Comment: That will work. I was making it harder than it needed to be. Thanks.